# Modifying a dictionary outside a function with multi-processing

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have two dictionaries `data` and `results` that are outside of my function `my_func`. I wish to create multiple processes that modify `results` to speed up execution of populating `results`.

```py
import multiprocessing
# create fake data 
vals = [f"test seq {i}" for i in range(100)]
data = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(vals)}
# dict for output 
results = {}
# func for filling results 
def my_func(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i not in results.keys():
            results[i] = data[i]
# create Process objects
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
processes = {}
for i in range(num_cores):
    processes[i] = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_func, args = [data])
# start processes
for i in range(num_cores):
    print('starting ',i)
    processes[i].start()
print(results)
```

However, when I run this, it just outputs an empty list

```py
starting  0
starting  1
{}
```

I tried debugging by checking if the function works without multiprocessing.

```py
# create fake data 
vals = [f"test seq {i}" for i in range(10)]
data = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(vals)}
# dict for output 
results = {}
my_func(data)
results
```

which outputs

```py
{0: 'test seq 0',
 1: 'test seq 1',
 2: 'test seq 2',
 3: 'test seq 3',
 4: 'test seq 4',
 5: 'test seq 5',
 6: 'test seq 6',
 7: 'test seq 7',
 8: 'test seq 8',
 9: 'test seq 9'}
```

So the populating function works just fine. I then tried debugging my multiprocessing logic.

```py
def write(s):
    print(s)

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
processes = {}
for i in range(num_cores):
    processes[i] = multiprocessing.Process(target=write, args = ['hello'])
for i in range(num_cores):
    print('starting ',i)
    processes[i].start()
```

which yields

```py
starting  0
starting  1
hello
hello
```

as expected.

Therefore, I'm stumped what the error is.

How do I get multiple processes to edit the same dictionary at once without having conflicts?

Comment: why are you using multi-processing and not multi-threading, altho sharing data with other processes is possible it's way slower

Comment: didn't realize what the difference was. someone just explained the difference. ur right, i'm using the wrong one. what's the right package for multi-threading?

Comment: Yup, that solved it